# How do I remove a value from a JSONB array column in Rails/Postgres?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

Given this column type:

```
# schema.db
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  ..
  t.jsonb "details", array: true
  ...
end
```

How can I remove a value by its index? My attempt ends up saving `nil` at the index.

```
u = User.find(1).details
=> [{"group"=>[{"type"=>"website", "value"=>"https://www.stackoverflow.com/"}, {"type"=>"phone", "value"=>"212 111 1212"}]}, {"group"=>[{"type"=>nil, "value"=>nil}]}]
u.details[1] = nil
u.save
=> ... }]}, nil]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.delete_at(index)` method

```
u = User.find(1).details
=> [{"group"=>[{"type"=>"website", "value"=>"https://www.stackoverflow.com/"}, {"type"=>"phone", "value"=>"212 111 1212"}]}, {"group"=>[{"type"=>nil, "value"=>nil}]}]
u.delete_at(1)
u.save
=> ... }]}]>
```

You can even delete the element from nested array too

```
u = User.find(1).details
=> [{"group"=>[{"type"=>"website", "value"=>"https://www.stackoverflow.com/"}, {"type"=>"phone", "value"=>"212 111 1212"}]}, {"group"=>[{"type"=>nil, "value"=>nil}]}]
u["group"].delete_at(2)
u.save
=> ... }]}]>
```